# Error while uploading file from S3 trigger lambda to an API endpoint

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, http-post, multipartform-data

I need to trigger a lambda whenever a file is uploaded to my S3 bucket. At every upload, I need to send the uploaded file to an API Gateway endpoint that accepts multipart form data.

I have tried many ways of uploading form data in my lambda (node), but I get an error every time.
The endpoint works fine, as I have tested it independently using Postman.

Can someone point me to the error in the below code (I am still new to Node.js).

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });


exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    // Get the object from the event and show its content type
    const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    const key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
        console.log('Bucket:', bucket);
        console.log('Key:', key);
    const params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: key,
    };
    try {
        const fileM = s3.getObject(params);
        console.log('Triggering API');
        const post_body = {
            "file" : fileM
        };
    
        const options = {
          hostname: 'somehostname.amazonaws.com',
          port: 80,
          path: 'someValidAPIURL',
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
          },
          formData: post_body
        };
    
    let data = '';
    let statusCode = '';
    const req = http.request(options, res => {
        statusCode = res.statusCode;
        console.log(`Email send API statusCode is: ${res.statusCode}`);
        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', () => {
            const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(parsedData);
            if(statusCode != 200) {
                // error handling
            } else {
                console.log(` API responded with status ::${statusCode}`);
                context.succeed(' API responded successfully');
            }
        });
    });
    
    req.on('error', (e) => {
        console.error(e);
        throw new Error('Error while initiating request to trigger the API');
    });
    
    req.write(post_body);
    
    req.end();
        
        
        
    } catch (err) {
        const message = `Error getting object ${key} from bucket ${bucket}`;
        console.log(err);
        throw new Error(message);
    }
};
```

I think there is an error in the way I am uploading file data. I have tried it in many other ways but could not succeed yet.

Comment: Well what is the error?

Comment: It says: the first argument should be a buffer or Uint8Array. This is what makes me think the HTTP call is going wrong

Comment: Please update the Q